# Line-wrapping problems with IPython shell

Tags: python, terminal, ipython

If I have run a long line in IPython, and try and recall it (using the up-arrow) or backspace beyond the start of the current line, it displays incorrectly (all smushed into one line)

For example, in the following session I wrote a long line `[1]`, entered a somewhat-blank line `[2]`, then up-arrowed twice to get the `print` statement on line `[3]`, and the following happened:

[image: Line wrap issue]

Happens in both iTerm and Terminal.app.. I had a similar problem with regular terminal sessions, which was fixed by properly terminating colour codes, but I'm not sure how to fix it with IPython

Comment: This problem haunted me for sooooo long.... I didn't realized until now, that IPython caused this. Tried "reset", "tput", "shopt -s checkwinsize", reset PS1, tmux resize-pane, escape chars magic, but all in vain.

Now I know, that it only occures if IPython has been invoked from TMux, and IPython was killed, or sent to the background (CTRL+Z).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aha! I had an old version of the Python readline module - installing the latest from http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/ and it works perfectly!

```
sudo easy_install http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/readline-2.5.1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg
```

Comment: Make sure you use easy_install, not pip. I tried "pip install readline" and while readline installed, I still had the problem with ipython. I uninstalled, then used easy_install, and problem solved.

Comment: Just tried, ``pip install readline`` now works just fine and solved the problem for me..

Comment: On my Linux Mint installation `pip install readline` required me to first install libncurses with `apt-get install libncurses5-dev`.

Answer (score 2):

Got this problem on Snow Leopard. Installing a new version of readline from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline/ fixes it:

```
sudo easy_install http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/r/readline/readline-2.6.4-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
```

Comment: My stock Snow Leopard has python2.6.1 and the 2.6.4 version did not work.  Also, here's the link to use an alternate mirror since the main pypi is slow lately.

sudo easy_install http://d.pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/r/readline/readline-2.6.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg

Comment: Good points. I should add that I am using the MacPorts version of python -- running 'python_select -s' returns 'python26' instead of 'python26-apple', which shows up in 'python_select -l'.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce it (up-arrow works for long lines in ipython):

[image: ipython up-arrow long line]

Comment: :/ That's really annoying, I've tried disabling any profile customisation, using the latest stable version (ipython 0.9.1), two different machines, using different terminal profiles.. What terminal emulator/shell/python/ipython version etc are you using?