# IPython OS X: Up arrow gives "^[[A"

Tags: macos, ipython

Whenever I hit the up arrow in IPython, instead of getting history, I get this set of characters "^[[A" (not including the quotes).

Hitting the down arrow gives "^[[B", and tab completion doesn't work (just enters a tab).

How can I fix this?  It happens in both Terminal and iTerm.

Running OS X 10.5, Framework Python 2.5.4.  Error occurs in both ipython 0.8.3 and ipython 0.9.1.  pyreadline-2.5.1 egg is installed in both cases.

(edit: SSH-ing to another linux machine and using IPython there works fine.  So does running the normal "python" command on the OS X machine.)

Cheers,
- Dan

Comment: I think this only started to occur recently and the versions from port don't seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're using an old version of the Python readline module, I had somewhat [similar problem to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670764/line-wrapping-problems-with-ipython-shell/672755#672755)

> Aha! I had an old version of the Python readline module - installing the latest from http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/ and it works perfectly!
>
> ```
> sudo easy_install http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/readline-2.5.1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg
> ```

Comment: Thank you @dbr!  Note for progeny: Find the current path to your readline by running: $ python -c 'import readline; print readline.__file__'.  Ultimately I fixed this by running: $ sudo pip install readline==6.2.4.1

Answer (score 2):

Solved by completely wiping all of site-packages.
I then re-installed Framework Python, re-installed setuptools, and easy_installed ipython FTW.